# Gorm: Is it possible to define shared methods for common db operations (e.g get by id)?

Tags: go, inheritance, go-gorm, code-reuse

Using `go` and `gorm` in a project.

I have created a `dao` level to wrap the database operations, each table has its own dao type.

---

### Current code

- `Get` method from `FirstDao` for `first` table and `FirstModel`:

  ```
  func (dao *FirstDao) Get(id uint64) (*model.FirstModel, error) {
  }
  ```
- `Get` method from `SecondDao` for `second` table and `SecondModel`:

  ```
  func (dao *SecondDao) Get(id uint64) (*model.SecondModel, error) {
  }
  ```

---

### What I want to achieve

Wondering is it possible to write a `BaseDao` in go, with a single `Get()` method, so that I don't have to write this code 2 times.

This is very easy in Java, but since go is very different, and don't support real inheritance (I guess), not sure is this possible.

---

### What I have tried

- Define a Model interface, and try to use refection. But failed.
  Main reason: inside the `Get()` method, it still need an instance of the original specific struct, e.g `model.FirstModel{}`, I pass it as interface `model.Model`, and can't use it as original type.
- struct embedding.
- Googling

---

### Questions

- Is it possible to do this?
- If not, why?
- If yes, how?

Comment: This is usually what `interface{}` is used for. I'm not familiar with gorm, but all the go encoding/decoding and marshal/unmarshal functions already use it so you don't need to bother with any reflection.

Comment: @super Yep, already found the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to completely bypass writing a `Get()` method for each DAO, your only solution is to return an `interface{}` from this method.
However this approach creates two problems :

- You need to manually cast the `interface{}` everywhere.
- You are sacrifying type safety.

The solution I think the best, is to share most of the code by using structure embedding, and write lightweight wrappers for each DAO to convert the unsafe `interface{}` into a type-safe value.

#### Example

First create your base DAO with a generic `Get()` method.
There is no type generics in Go, so you should return an `interface{}` here.

```golang
type BaseDAO struct {}

func (*BaseDAO) Get(id uint64) (interface{}, error) {}
```

Then, for each type of data, create a specific DAO implementation, embedding `BaseDAO` :

```golang
type FooModel = string

type FooDAO struct {
    // Embbeding BaseDAO by not specifying a name on this field
    // BaseDAO methods can be called from FooDAO instances
    BaseDAO
}

func (foo *FooDAO) Get(id uint64) (FooModel, error) {
    // Call the shared Get() method from BaseDAO.
    // You can see this just like a `super.Get()` call in Java.
    result, _ := foo.BaseDAO.Get(id)
    return result.(FooModel), nil
}
```

Comment: I have refactored the code similar as the answer describes. Now the code of sub DAOs are much more neat. BTW, in the answer `result, _ := foo.BaseDAO.Get(id)`, should pass the model as first param.

Answer (score 1):

```golang
type BaseDao struct {
    FirstDao
    SecondDao
}

func (dao *BaseDao) Get(id uint64) (*model.SecondModel, error) {
}
```

Just writing my thoughts. Probably this will help you finc your solution

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can't. Because go dose not support genrics before go 1.18.

I think extract `dao` layer maybe a anti-pattern if you want to use [hook](https://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html).

Imagine that:

```
// pkg models
type User
type UserChangeLog

// hook
func (user *User) afterUpdate(tx) error () {
  // if you want to record user changes
  userChangeLogDao().insert(user)
}
```

```
// pkg dao
func (userDao) update() {}
func (userChangeLogDao) insert(User){}
```

it cause `import cycle` between dao and model